# Sublime Text 3 package control seems gone

Tags: sublimetext3

I need to install the package control, but the relevant sites seem not to work at this moment. https://packagecontrol.io/ is down. Scott Granneman's page is working, but it only tells you how to install it. It refers to  http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation which is down too. https://github.com/wbond/package_control is available, but I have no idea at all what I should do to install it. What do I need to do to install the package control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @jaswanth-jesse mentioned, Linode is undergoing a DDos attack. The status can be checked here:
https://status.linode.com/